# GSpread - get also None-values when reading?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

i want to read data from google sheets using gspread - but i also want the None values in the nested list -

I read the data with the following code and it works fine:

```
FN = "TestSheetGSPREAD"
wb1 = gc.open (FN)
ws1 = wb1.get_worksheet(0)
data = ws1.get('A3:H100').value
```

In the google sheet only the first column A is filled - the rest of the columns is empty.

Now i get this result:

```
[['AAPL'], ['FB'], ['MSFT'], ['AMZN'], ['CAT'], ['V'], ['BAYN.DE']]
```

But i want also the None / "" values in the result - like:

```
[['AAPL',None,None,None,None,None,None,None],...]
```

Is this somehow possible using Gspread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the methods of spreadsheets.values.get and spreadsheets.values.batchGet of Sheets API are used, the empty cells of the end of column cannot be retrieved as `""`. When the method of spreadsheets.get is used, the empty cells of the end of column like `""` can be confirmed by checking `userEnteredValue` and `effectiveValue`. But in this case, the script is a bit complicated. So in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Export the Spreadsheet as CSV data. In this case, you can use the range.
2. Parse the CSV data to a list.

By this flow, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved. When this workaround is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials) # About "credentials", please use your script here.

FN = "TestSheetGSPREAD"
wb1 = gc.open(FN)
ws1 = wb1.get_worksheet(0)
access_token = credentials.get_access_token().access_token
rng = 'A3:H100'
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + wb1.id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + str(ws1.id) + '&range=' + quote(rng)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = list(csv.reader(io.StringIO(res.text)))
print(data)

# If you want to convert "" to None, please use the following script.
result = [[c or None for c in r] for r in data]
print(result)
```

#### Reference:

- [Using google query to download parts of a published sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48511747)

Comment: By the way, in this sample, please include the libralies of `import csv`, `import io`, `import requests` and `from urllib.parse import quote`.